# Matlab - Cumulative Distribution of trajectory

Tags: matlab, function, histogram, distribution, motion

To the best of my knowledge,I did not find any answers anywhere to the answer to my problem. I consider myself pretty decent in Matlab.

I have the trajectory of a tumor recorded vs time [like on this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2KQ8.png). I would like to compute cumulative distribution that would show the time vs displacement of the tumor from its ideal position at x=0 [like on this picture generated with another software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNNm3.png).

What the cumulative graph means is that we can find the total time outside a certain position the tumor spent during acquisition. You see that the position of the tumor at the position 0 is the length of the entire acquisition time(~300 seconds).If we are looking for the time the tumor spent outside 1.1 mm from their ideal position, it would indicate ~100 seconds.The time the tumor spent outside 2.8mm becomes really close to 0s.

Any code that would help me get such a  would be great. I strongly sense that there is something to do with cumsum, cdf etc, but I really have not managed to find a proper function. My next option would be to bin it myself and write the code for it.

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the distribution using `hist(x)`. Then by calculating the backwards `cumsum()` you can draw the desired plot.

```
clc, clear all, close all
seconds = 303;              % Amount of time that passed during the test
datapoints = 3000;          % Amount of Datapoints in your vector 

x = randn(datapoints,1);
[counts,centers] = hist(abs(x),sort([0;unique(abs(x))]));

sumX = sum(counts);
cumsumX = cumsum(counts);
time = (sumX - [0 cumsumX(1:end-1)])*seconds/datapoints; % Normalize result with factor

figure
plot(centers, time)
```

Comment: Hi Dennis Klopfer,  

This definitely helps me toward what I am seeking. I'd like however to be able to have the plot at the end with the time as a y-coordinates. If we had a trajectories of position vs time, like the following code : `x = randn(3000,1);
time = cumsum(ones(3000,1));`,   what would be the best way of plotting 

`plot(centers, time` ?   

Thanks,   

Vincent

Comment: I have updated my answer. If this answeres your question I'd be glad if you accept the answer. If you have more questions let me know.

Comment: Great :) Thanks a lot for that !